# Is it possible to authenticate users with an on-premise legacy system via an iFrame in a Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

Anyone here use Force.com User Authentication approach for a composite integration with a on-premise legacy system via an iFrame in a Visualforce page?

I can't implement SSO in this scenario for SFDC and/or the client application. I need to use SFDC essentially as the Identity Provider, passing the SessionID and API URL to the client for authentication / validation on the client side.

I'll be using SSL (HTTPS) per the documentation to ensure the SessionID and URL are encrypted during transport from SFDC to On-Premise DB.

Are there any gotchas I need to be aware of? Architecturally is FUA a sound approach to integrating SFDC and an On-Premise Application? Are there any other options?

Broad question I know.....

Comment: A touch broad, let me get some assumptions out of the way.
1. The iFrame in a visualforce page would point to the clients third party site?
2. the client third party site would call back to a visualforce page to authenticate the credentials and then create a session for the user on the third party site?

In this scenario I dont know if you can authenticate against the user object directly in apex without customizing the object, effectively creating your own authentication scheme.

Comment: As I think about it, instead of a custom webservice on SF you could authenticate through the API. everyone would need access from the profile, but that would use the standard authentication scheme.

Comment: 1. Yes. Visualforce Page has iFrame. iFrame source points to a on-premise site like HTTPS://legacyapp.domain.com/showItems?SessionID=XYZ&URL=https://na9.salesforce.com/SOAP/25.0&User=someuser@test.com.

Comment: 2. Correct. On-Premise would invoke Force.com SOAP API, pass along the SessionID and use the URL passed along to validate Session is valid. I.E. User is logged In SFDC.

Comment: And agreed. Its a broad question I know!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of other options to consider

1) Each salesforce org contains a SAML Identity Provider; if your target application speaks SAML you can simply configure the IDP and send SAML Assertions

2) Each salesforce org can perform Single Sign-On with OAuth.  Implement OAuth in your application, and we'll pass an "id" parameter as part of the OAuth response.  You can use the OAuth access token to pull Identity information from the URL passed in this ID as well as call the APIs

Comment: Thanks. Unfortanetly I can't use SSO for a few reasons. I was pushing for that initially but got shot down if you can believe it! I am curious about the SAML provider though. Interesting I'll have to look into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just to note that if the iframe gets into an HTTPS page, and the surrounding frame is HTTP - IE will likely throw out some security related errors to the user.

Comment: Yeah, this will be HTTPS (Visualforce Page) and HTTPS on the client site.